# Show only the last 4 weeks of data in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an issue with the time scope of the chart (chartjs). In this case, I only want to show labels and data from the last 4 ISO weeks. Is any kindred spirit out that got knowledge about this?

[This is an image of the current chart I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUAQA.png)

*(in this case, it would only show weeks 31, 32, 33, and 34. And next week would 31 disappear and week 35 appear even if no data is made in the API)*

[This is the API I use (Sorted by weeks, and cleaned)](https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/an675a1pxghf6?sheet=Strava:weekly)

[This is the raw API data(Not sorted by weeks, but instead dates and have much other irrelevant data)](https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/an675a1pxghf6?sheet=Strava)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chart.js, the Missing Manual</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(75, 192, 192, 1);
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(75, 192, 192, 1);
        background: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chartMenu">
      <p>Hi dear friend</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.1.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-Tfw6etYMUhL4RTki37niav99C6OHwMDB2iBT5S5piyHO+ltK2YX8Hjy9TXxhE1Gm/TmAV0uaykSpnHKFIAif/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
    // data block
    var week = [], kilometer = [], pushups = [], situps = []
    
    

    async function dummyChart () {
    await getDummyData()

    const data = {
      labels: week,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Kilometer',
        data: kilometer,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
          offset: 5,
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
    };

    // config block
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
              }
        } 
      },
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
    };
     // init render block
     const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
  }
  dummyChart()

    // Fetch data from API
    async function getDummyData() {
      const apiUrl = "https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/an675a1pxghf6?sheet=Strava:weekly"

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
      const lineChartData = await response.json()
     
      const weekdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.week)
      const kilometerdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.kilometer)
      const pushupsdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.pushups)
      const situpsdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.situps)
    
      console.log(kilometerdata, pushupsdata, situpsdata)

      kilometer = kilometerdata
      pushups = pushupsdata
      situps = situpsdata
      week = weekdata

    }
</script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share some snippets of your code?

Comment: This isn't about chartjs. This is about the data you send into chartjs. Do `arr.slice(-4)` if the array is already sorted. Otherwise, you need to find the highest 4 week numbers. This assumes that week numbers constantly go up, and are not based on weeks of the year (in which case the week 1 of 2022 is later than week 52 of 2021).

Comment: @MaxCode , thanks for showing support. I added all my code into the window above. Kind regards

Comment: @EmilKarlsson, I added my code above. How could you use arr.slice(-4) from a fetch? I tried to google it a bit. I might need to put more effort into this to truly understand it - Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I added a ".slice(-4)" under the labels and data. and it did work!  not sure if this is a solid way to do it but thanks @emilkarlsson

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chart.js, the Missing Manual</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(75, 192, 192, 1);
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(75, 192, 192, 1);
        background: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chartMenu">
      <p>Hi dear friend</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.1.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-Tfw6etYMUhL4RTki37niav99C6OHwMDB2iBT5S5piyHO+ltK2YX8Hjy9TXxhE1Gm/TmAV0uaykSpnHKFIAif/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
    // data block
    var week = [], kilometer = [], pushups = [], situps = []
    
    

    async function dummyChart () {
    await getDummyData()

    const data = {
      labels: week.slice(-4),
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Kilometer',
        data: kilometer.slice(-4),
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
          offset: 5,
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
    };

    // config block
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
              }
        } 
      },
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
    };
     // init render block
     const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
  }
  dummyChart()

    // Fetch data from API
    async function getDummyData() {
      const apiUrl = "https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/an675a1pxghf6?sheet=Strava:weekly"

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
      const lineChartData = await response.json()
     
      const weekdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.week)
      const kilometerdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.kilometer)
      const pushupsdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.pushups)
      const situpsdata = lineChartData.map( (x) => x.situps)
    
      console.log(kilometerdata, pushupsdata, situpsdata)

      kilometer = kilometerdata
      pushups = pushupsdata
      situps = situpsdata
      week = weekdata

    }
</script>


 </body>
</html>
```